# Suggestion for using Location Services in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am creating a app that's going to show my location and some other devices location in the map. I don't know exactly the procedure needed to do this. I know I m gonna use Google Map V2 and location API. But not sure about what else I need. Can anyone please tell me the instructions abstractly?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more !! Why you need other devices location ?

Comment: I need the other devices location cause i m gonna need to get location from vehicles later on. @TalhaQ

Comment: Allright other devices also use your app.So you want to make an app which shows your location and also other devices location which are using your app.Am i right?

Comment: So its like placing your friends/peoples location on the map and see where your friends/peoples are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is the Google Map v2 and server might saved different people locations.Please Check this [link](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435).How to setup Map API v2.Also you should need a service which collects your location and sends to server which sends it to other devices and shows on map on other devices.

Why is the need of server here?
The application shows only the location of current device but you want to get the location of other devices which are using your app.So send every device location to server which collects it and store it.Now after certain interval of time send these location(latitude,longitude) to every device which is using your app and plot them on the map.
If you still have any trouble comment here.Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks @talhaQ. I'll try and let you know. :-)